# How to bind a dropdown list in a gridview's edit template

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a `gridview` that is connected to an `sqldatasource`, my `select` statement joins two tables, Survey & Category. a column in Survey is `Cateogry_ID` which refers to the primary key of the category table "ID". The join i created is to show the category name instead of the ID.

```
SELECT 
S.[ID], 
S.[Survey_Name], 
S.[Start_Date], 
S.[End_Date], 
C.[Category_Name], 
S.[Username], 
S.[Picture],
S.[Audience] 
FROM [Survey] S
Inner Join
Category C On S.Category_ID = C.ID
```

when the admin wants to update the survey table and wants to update the category, I only want him to pick from the names in the `category_name` column from `category` table.. How can I bind a dropdownlist in the edit template of that column and achieve this in design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a working example of binding table column in sql to gridview here. [how-to-bind-a-dropdownlist-with-a-edititemtemplate-in-the-gridview](http://chalaki.com/how-to-bind-a-dropdownlist-with-a-edititemtemplate-in-the-gridview/652/) use your column name there to achieve the same.

There's a

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDistinctDS"
 DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("your column name") %>' >
 </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But is it wrong to add an sqldatasource for for just this drop down box? or its ok to add as many as i want?

Answer (score 0):

check this site to use the edit template by what u can use your desired controls.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.ASPX